# GitHubへ登録した公開鍵が勝手に削除される事はありますか？

Tags: github

GitHubへ登録した(はずの)公開鍵が見つかりません
GitHubへ登録した公開鍵が削除される要件は何ですか？
自分で削除する以外に、削除される可能性としては何が挙げられますか？

Comment: どうやら、1年以上使用しないととセキュリティーの問題で削除されることがあるようですね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[コメント欄](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55957/github%e3%81%b8%e7%99%bb%e9%8c%b2%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e5%85%ac%e9%96%8b%e9%8d%b5%e3%81%8c%e5%8b%9d%e6%89%8b%e3%81%ab%e5%89%8a%e9%99%a4%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b%e4%ba%8b%e3%81%af%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b#comment60155_55957) でも言及されていますが、GitHub のヘルプページに明記されていました。

[SSH キーの削除または紛失 - GitHub ヘルプ](https://help.github.com/ja/github/authenticating-to-github/deleted-or-missing-ssh-keys)

> **セキュリティ上の理由から、過去 1 年間使用されていない SSH キーを GitHubは自動的に削除します。**
>
> GitHub は使われていない SSH キーを自動的に削除し、アカウントを安全に保ちます。
>   たとえば退職者が出たときやコンピューターを紛失したときです。